# Sharepoint hosted client app part custom properties validation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part, client-webpart

I am trying to validation custom properties of client web part in Sharepoint hosted app. Not finding anything to do so.
I have custom properties which are required ,url validation , character limit in textbox etc.  How can I achieve this.